# Creating stored procedure using cfstoredproc

Tags: stored-procedures, coldfusion, sql-server-2012, railo, cfstoredproc

Is is possible to **create** a stored procedure using cfstoredproc? When I run the following I get *Incorrect syntax near 'GO'*.

```
<cffile action="read" file="mypath/myFile.sql" variable="sp_1">

<cfstoredproc procedure="sp_executesql" dataSource="#getDatasource()#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_varchar" value ='#sp_1#'>
</cfstoredproc>
```

myFile.sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('getMyData', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC getMyData
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE getMyData
    @some_var    AS NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE  @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM myTable where id = ''' + @some_var + ''' '

    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql 

END


<cfquery name="createGetMyData" dataSource="#getDatasource()#">
    #preservesinglequotes(sp_1)#
</cfquery>
```

[image: result from running cfquery]

Comment: If you run that code in SSMS does it create the procedure or does it throw an error?

Comment: Gotta be something the drive doesn't like or is misinterpreting. The only things I see is the "PROC" ... I usually see it spelled out as PROCEDURE.

Comment: Here are a few other things. input vars are usually in parens - as in `CREATE PROCEDURE getMyData (@some_var AS NVARCHAR(200))` I don't usually see a semicolon after set nocount on (or if I do they are used throughout). When quoted identifiers are ON I usually see user identifiers or dbo as in [dbo].[getMyData] ... and in the select statement. I don't use them routinely either - just adding that to the mix :)

Comment: I do not have time to write up a full answer right now, but `GO` is a special keyword. IIRC, it will not work outside of SSMS or `sqlcmd`. Try restructuring the sql logic to eliminate the need for `GO`.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the issue. [From the docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) *"`GO` is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor... requires no permissions. It can be executed by any user."*

Comment: Rats.. I just added that info to my answer. Leigh beats me out again. I love her!! :D

Comment: creating the SP in SSMS i get no issues. I've changed using "PROC" to "procedure" i've also removed the semicolon after set nocount. I still get the same error of syntax near GO

Comment: Is there a way around this?

Comment: split your statements in 2. no matter what you do your create procedure statement has to be the first item of the batch that creates it. So run one query to drop the proc and another to creaete it.  leave out the ANSI NULLS statement and the quoted identifier statements. They are likely defaulted on your server anyway. Or leave them in WITHOUT the "go" line.

Comment: Cool, i'll try that out. I suppose I can check if the SP exists and run an exec('create proc') and then run an alter proc. I'll give that a go.

Comment: yeah.. moves a bit more of your logic into CF but suitable I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<cffile action="read" file="mypath/myFile.sql" variable="sp_1">

<cfstoredproc procedure="sp_executesql" dataSource="#getDatasource()#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_varchar" value ='#preservesinglequotes(sp_1)#'>
</cfstoredproc>
```

ColdFusion escapes your single quotes in db variables.

EDIT:

Secondly there is the batching of statements. the drive will batch your query as a single statement wheras the "GO" keyword is an indicator of a batch prepared. In other words, your "GO" actually IS the issue.

To fix it you will need to run 2 querys - one to drop and the other to create. Why? Because CREATE PROCEDURE actually *has to be the first* statement in a given batch. in MSSQL studio, using GO, you are creating 3 batches, now you have to figure out how to use one.

The good news is that your ANSI nulls and Quoted identifiers are probably not needed - they are defaulted on most instances.

Does this help?

Comment: Still get the same error Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. When I execute the code to create the stored procedure directly on the DB I don't have a problem

Comment: And when you try it with cfquery (again use preservesinglequotes())?

Comment: same again with cfquery